# Double Counting When Using Accumulators with Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a very simple two lines program.  I am getting input from Kafka and I am saving the input in a file and counting the input received using accumulator.

My code looks like this, when I run this code I am getting two accumulator count for each input.

```
HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();  kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list",    "localhost:9092");   kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream( jssc, String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topicsSet);
final Accumulator<Integer> accum = jssc.sparkContext().accumulator(0);
JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(
new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
               public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) { accum.add(1); return tuple2._2(); 
} });
lines.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception { 
if(!rdd.isEmpty() || !rdd.partitions().isEmpty()){ rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/testDirJan4/test1.text");}
System.out.println(" &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& COUNT OF ACCUMULATOR IS " + accum.value()); return null;} 
 });
 jssc.start();
```

If I remove this saveAsTextFile I get correct count with this line I am getting double counting.

```
Here are the Stack trace with SaveAsText statement Please see double counting below:

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& BEFORE COUNT OF ACCUMULATOR IS &&&&&&&&&&&&&&& 0
INFO : org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Starting job: foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Got job 0 (foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90) with 1 output partitions
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Final stage: ResultStage 0(foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90)
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Parents of final stage: List()
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Missing parents: List()
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at KafkaURLStreaming.java:83), which has no missing parents
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - ensureFreeSpace(3856) called with curMem=0, maxMem=1893865881
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.8 KB, free 1806.1 MB)
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - ensureFreeSpace(2225) called with curMem=3856, maxMem=1893865881
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.2 KB, free 1806.1 MB)
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo - Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:51637 (size: 2.2 KB, free: 1806.1 MB)
INFO : org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at KafkaURLStreaming.java:83)
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl - Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, ANY, 2026 bytes)
INFO : org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD - Computing topic test11, partition 0 offsets 36 -> 37
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Verifying properties
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property fetch.message.max.bytes is overridden to 1073741824
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property group.id is overridden to 
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to localhost:2181
INFO : com.markmonitor.antifraud.ce.KafkaURLStreaming - #################  Input json stream data  ################# one test message
INFO : org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 972 bytes result sent to driver
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - ResultStage 0 (foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90) finished in 0.133 s
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 116 ms on localhost (1/1)
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl - Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Job 0 finished: foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90, took 0.496657 s
INFO : org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner - Cleaned accumulator 2
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo - Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on localhost:51637 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 1806.1 MB)
INFO : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
INFO : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
INFO : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
INFO : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
INFO : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
INFO : org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Starting job: foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Got job 1 (foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90) with 1 output partitions
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Final stage: ResultStage 1(foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90)
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Parents of final stage: List()
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Missing parents: List()
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Submitting ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90), which has no missing parents
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - ensureFreeSpace(97104) called with curMem=0, maxMem=1893865881
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 94.8 KB, free 1806.0 MB)
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - ensureFreeSpace(32204) called with curMem=97104, maxMem=1893865881
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 31.4 KB, free 1806.0 MB)
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo - Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:51637 (size: 31.4 KB, free: 1806.1 MB)
INFO : org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90)
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl - Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, ANY, 2026 bytes)
INFO : org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
INFO : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
INFO : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
INFO : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
INFO : org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD - Computing topic test11, partition 0 offsets 36 -> 37
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Verifying properties
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property fetch.message.max.bytes is overridden to 1073741824
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property group.id is overridden to 
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to localhost:2181
INFO : com.markmonitor.antifraud.ce.KafkaURLStreaming - #################  Input json stream data  ################# one test message
INFO : org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - Saved output of task 'attempt_201601050824_0001_m_000000_1' to hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/testDirJan4/test1.text/_temporary/0/task_201601050824_0001_m_000000
INFO : org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil - attempt_201601050824_0001_m_000000_1: Committed
INFO : org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1). 933 bytes result sent to driver
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - ResultStage 1 (foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90) finished in 0.758 s
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Job 1 finished: foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90, took 0.888585 s
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) in 760 ms on localhost (1/1)
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl - Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& AFTER COUNT OF ACCUMULATOR IS 2

But if I comment the saveAsText then I am getting correct count as one for each input.

INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - ensureFreeSpace(2227) called with curMem=9937, maxMem=1893865881
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.2 KB, free 1806.1 MB)
INFO : org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo - Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:58397 (size: 2.2 KB, free: 1806.1 MB)
INFO : org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at KafkaURLStreaming.java:83)
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl - Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, ANY, 2026 bytes)
INFO : org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
INFO : org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD - Computing topic test11, partition 0 offsets 37 -> 38
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Verifying properties
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property fetch.message.max.bytes is overridden to 1073741824
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property group.id is overridden to 
INFO : kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to localhost:2181
INFO : com.markmonitor.antifraud.ce.KafkaURLStreaming - #################  Input json stream data  ################# one test message without saveAs
INFO : org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1). 987 bytes result sent to driver
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - ResultStage 1 (foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90) finished in 0.103 s
INFO : org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Job 1 finished: foreachRDD at KafkaURLStreaming.java:90, took 0.151210 s
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& AFTER COUNT OF ACCUMULATOR IS 1
```

Comment: _In transformations, users should be aware of that each task’s update may be applied more than once if tasks or job stages are re-executed._ - [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators-a-nameaccumlinka)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no garanty in a **spark Trasformation** that accumulator will be called only once.

For more in deep answer read spark guide here:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators-a-nameaccumlinka

just extracted from above:

For accumulator updates performed inside actions only, Spark guarantees that each task’s update to the accumulator will only be applied once, i.e. restarted tasks will not update the value. In transformations, users should be aware of that each task’s update may be applied more than once if tasks or job stages are re-executed.

Hope it will help you